# use of Vuex without precompilation

Tags: vue.js, build, vuex

I am trying to use Vuex inside my application. I have just a single note, I cannot do a transpilation on my vue components, so I load them using the following script:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/http-vue-loader"></script>
```

and I am declaring them as

```
    new window.Vue({
        el: '#app',
        store: // what I am trying to to
        components: {
            'fiche-form-content': window.httpVueLoader('/gestion/vue/composants/article-site-form.vue'),
            'fiche-list': window.httpVueLoader('/gestion/vue/composants/article-site-list.vue')
        },
    })
```

Is it possible to call Vuex through a CDN, write it as a regular Vue store application and inject it without transpilation ? I am new to not using the Vue-cli or webpack on my apps and having no build, so if some one have a better understanding than me I would be happy you share your knowledges. thks